# Date picker examples for mvc3 using jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, date

i am new to mvc3 and view engine is razor, how to get date picker in my view. where should i write date picker function to effect it all view commonly. how can call it in my every view.

Answer (score 3):

You could add some common class to all input fields that need to be shown as datepicker:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeDate, new { @class = "date" })
```

and then in a separate javascript file:

```
$(function() {
    $('.date').datepicker();
});
```

then all you have to do is to include this .js file in your Layout so that it executes for each page and each input field possessing the date class.

Comment: It seems really easy to use, I'll certainly use this too. But, haven't you forgotten the .js file you're talking about?

Answer (score 2):

1. in _Layout.cshtml add following lines

//CSS

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"   />
```

//SCRIPTS

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

1. navigate to the Shared folder and there create a folder with a name EditorTemplates
2. inside EditorTemplates folder create a partial view called DateTime
3. add the following code to DateTime partial view

   @model System.DateTime ?
               @Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty), new { @class = "pickDate" })

   ```
       <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('.pickDate').datepicker({ 
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true
                });
            });
       </script>
   ```

Now you have everything set, and on every view where you have a field that is of DateTime type you'll see a jqueryUI datepicker when clicked inside that field or if you modify it's properties when clicked on icon etc.

For an example your view is just as it's created from model, you don't need to add nothing to it.

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

You probably have some kind of scripts collison. Try adding

```
@if(false)
{
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
}
```

on top of your view.

Comment: it's working i updated scripts you need to include to Layout. One script wasn't showned. Try it now.

Comment: it is working but i have another two jquery change functions witch are used to fill the text box when we select a value from drop down that is not working, and css of date picker effecting to my tree view and the font of tree view becoming small. so how can i use this with all functionality work properly.

Comment: use your jqueryui css and scripts normally, this isn't affectiong your code in any way

Comment: i copied all three files in to individual files and used in my project

Comment: i posted css and libraries from Google CDN and probably if you modified jqueryui script or css the tree view is small and drop-down isn't working. Try using your scripts instead of ones in example. This code is fully working and i don't know where is the collision with your code, inspect with chrome debugger when you use dropdownlist. Regards

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> with out using the above script all other controlls are working properly but when using the script not working. if i am not used the script i am not getting date picker

Comment: same problem still i am not getting date picker, if i remove if(false){} i am getting date picker that will causes above problem.

Comment: Have you tried Google Chrome Developer Tools (CTRL+SHIFT+I) and refreshing the page then go to Console tab, and you will see possible javascript errors.